# Why am I recieving a null pointer exception?

Tags: java, jsp, tomcat, cassandra

So I am trying to implement a user profile page, I've implemeted it using a bean, servlet and a corresponding jsp page.

When I try to visit /profile/username (the account definitely exists in the database), I get the following error displayed in my browser:

```
exception

org.apache.jasper.JasperException: An exception occurred processing JSP page /profile.jsp at line 87

84:         <div class="container">
85:             <div class="row">
86:                 <div class="col-lg-12 text-center user-profile">
87:                     <h1>Welcome <%=profile.getUsername()%>!</h1>
88:                 </div>
89:                 <div class="col-sm-4 text-center">
90:                     <div class="user-post" style="background-color: red">


Stacktrace:
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.handleJspException(JspServletWrapper.java:574)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:476)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:396)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:340)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:729)
    org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
    org.netbeans.modules.web.monitor.server.MonitorFilter.doFilter(MonitorFilter.java:393)
    [PACKAGE].servlets.Profile.doGet(Profile.java:47)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:622)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:729)
    org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
    org.netbeans.modules.web.monitor.server.MonitorFilter.doFilter(MonitorFilter.java:393)

root cause

java.lang.NullPointerException
    org.apache.jsp.profile_jsp._jspService(profile_jsp.java:218)
    org.apache.jasper.runtime.HttpJspBase.service(HttpJspBase.java:70)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:729)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:438)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:396)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:340)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:729)
    org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
    org.netbeans.modules.web.monitor.server.MonitorFilter.doFilter(MonitorFilter.java:393)
    [PACKAGE].servlets.Profile.doGet(Profile.java:47)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:622)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:729)
    org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
    org.netbeans.modules.web.monitor.server.MonitorFilter.doFilter(MonitorFilter.java:393)
```

When I go to where the error is (line 47 of the servlet Profile.java) it's just:

```
rd.forward(request, response);
```

I'm using the code exactly as I do in other servlets but it just doesn't work.

Am I missing something really obvious? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Believe the JVM - there's a null reference, in spite of your protestations.  You'll make faster progress if you stop insisting that you're correct.  The JVM is not persecuting you.  Step more carefully in the debugger until you find it.

Comment: if you are getting exception at this `rd.forward(request, response);` line then `rd` is null.

Comment: I'm trying to wrap my head around using a `JOptionPane` in a servlet...

Comment: If you receive a null pointer exception, then there is a null reference somewhere. It's hard to tell without debugging your program, but keep testing it.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder It was just for debugging, I don't believe I have access to the logs to use System.out.println

Comment: Does your ProfileStore constructor set the username?

Comment: @FMC ProfileStore constructor sets the user name yes from loading it from the User passed through to it

Comment: @duffymo I did more digging just like you said, I was loading the resource from the wrong place (storing it in session, trying to load it from response)

Comment: Very good.  Remember that.  It's always your code.

Answer (score 1):

You commented (on a deleted answer):

> Sorry I should've added the full jsp page, I declare profile above as follows:
>
> ```
>  ProfileStore profile = (ProfileStore) session.getAttribute("Profile");
> ```

.... but you set the attribute in the servlet code like this:

```
request.setAttribute("Profile", profile);
```

You should use the same "scoping" when setting and getting the attribute.  If you fetch an attribute that is not defined in the scope you are trying to fetch it from, then you will get a `null`.

Comment: Ahh I see, but am I not setting and getting the same attribute here? Both names of the attribute are uppercase 'Profile', or is it a case that it's not accessible to the jsp page?

Comment: `session` and `request` are different scopes.  Yes both scopes are accessible in a JSP.  But if you put an attribute into one scope and look for it in the other .... you won't find it!

Comment: Okay I'll look into this further, also I only have 6 reputation so it wasn't me that downvoted.

Comment: Sounds like the right answer to me.  Up vote on principle.